# How to stop pandas from appending to existing dataframe on a loop?

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe, data-analysis

I have a function to check whether the 20 day EMA of a stock is less than current market price.
And I have a list of stock tickers which invokes the function to check for condition explained above. But once my dataframe 'required_data' and 'ema_frame' is created after first ticker, it is immediately appending the values of next ticker's to previouly created dataframe. Instead of making a new dataframe with values for now supplied ticker.

My code looks like this [function to compare]

```
def check_for_ema_validity(ticker): 
    list_of_valid = []
    required_data = make_time_series(ticker).drop_duplicates()
    print(required_data)
    ema_series = TA.EMA(required_data, period = 20)
    ema_frame = pd.DataFrame(ema_series, columns= ['20 period EMA']).drop_duplicates()
    print(ema_frame)
    if required_data['close'].iloc[-1] > ema_frame['20 period EMA'].iloc[-1]:
        list_of_valid.append(ticker)
    return list_of_valid
```

for invoking the function I have a loop implemented as:

```
ticker_list = ['MCX', 'KEI', 'TATASTEEL', 'GUJALKALI']
for ticker in ticker_list:
    valid = check_for_ema_validity(ticker)
```

for the first ticker I'm getting a required_data, dataframe of [186 rows x 5 columns] printed (which is correct)
but for the second ticker i'm getting [372 rows x 5 columns] which is getting appended down to fist generated dataframe. And so on.. getting doubled

This is causing error in ema calculation for next ticker, How to solve this ? Please help

What I have tried:
added drop_duplicates, added del dataframe after end of comparison. Unfortunately none of them helped. Thank you.

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Pt0H.jpg)

Comment: please **dont** use `list` as a variable name since it's a build-in function. Furthermore where is `list` defined? You append to it but its not created

Comment: list is declared as an empty list. However, I have changed list to list_of_valid. Still the same thing is happening

Comment: where is it declared? If its delcared outside the function, then you append to the same list in each iteration

Comment: It was declared outside the function. Now I have declared inside the function. But the problem is still persisting. The problem is with required_data and ema_frame which is continuously getting appended. If I call the function individually with which each ticker, then no problem. The whole thing messes up when it is on loop.

Comment: Can you please update your question with the current code?

Comment: added to the question